# C# Gridview Header style not applied on sorting

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, gridview

I cant figure out why `SortedDescendingHeaderStyle-CssClass` and `SortedAscendingHeaderStyle-CssClass` are getting applied to the headers on sorting my `GridView`?

Here is my markup. Do I need to configure it in code behind?

```
.ascending a
    {
        background: url(/images/asc.gif) right no-repeat;
        display: block;
        padding: 0 25px 0 5px;
    }

    .descending a
    {
        background: url(/images/desc.gif) right no-repeat;
        display: block;
        padding: 0 25px 0 5px;
    }

<asp:GridView ID="gvOrderItems" runat="server" GridLines="None" CellSpacing="-1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" SortedAscendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="ascending"
  AllowSorting="true" OnRowDataBound="gvOrderItems_RowDataBound" SortedDescendingHeaderStyle-CssClass="descending" OnSorting="gvOrderItems_Sorting" EnableViewState="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" OnPageIndexChanging="gvOrderItems_PageIndexChanging1">                       
  <Columns>                             
    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderDate" HeaderText="Date" HeaderStyle-Font-Underline="true" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" ControlStyle-Font-Underline="true" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" SortExpression="OrderDate" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderNumber" HeaderText="Order Number" HeaderStyle-Font-Underline="true" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" SortExpression="OrderNumber" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="SKUNumber" HeaderText="Product Number" HeaderStyle-Font-Underline="true" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" SortExpression="SKUNumber" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderItemSKUName" HeaderText="Product Description" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="mtrx_Code2" HeaderText="Size" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderItemUnitCount" HeaderText="OTY" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderItemStatus" HeaderText="Status" />        
  </Columns>
  <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" CssClass="cssPager"/>    

</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Did you try to sort data and check whether class is applied or not?

Comment: Your GridView may have to be bound to a data source in markup for that to work automatically.

Comment: Hi Piyush class never gets applied when I sort the data? Is there anyway I can add it via code perhaps during sorting event?

Comment: Ok got something working. I am able to target the headers while setting the sorting direction like this `gvOrderItems.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "descending";`. However one issue it adds style to all the headers then. How can I target the current sort header?

Comment: Did you try with `gvOrderItems.Columns[n].HeaderStyle.CssClass` (where n is the index of the sorted column)?

Comment: yes ConnorsFan that works grand but how to get the current column index?

Comment: In the `Sorting` event, you can loop through the columns and get the one with the same `SortExpression` as `e.SortExpression`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to ConnorsFan I was able to resolve this. Basically looping through the columns and matching the requested sort expression to obtain the index of the column. Here is my solution

```
foreach (DataControlField col in gvOrderItems.Columns)
{
    if (col.SortExpression == sortExpression)
    {
      int index = gvOrderItems.Columns.IndexOf(col);
      gvOrderItems.Columns[index].HeaderStyle.CssClass = "descending"; 
    }
}
```